# Unable to make hyperlinks vertical-aligned in the center inside a nav tag

Tags: css, html

I have this sort of navigation bar implemented. My problem is that, no matter how I try to tune style for both nav and hyperlinks inside, I can't make text vertically centered, links are always shown in the very top of the hyperlink boxes. `vertical-alignment: middle` should be the solution, but nothing happens and the result remains the same.

PS: I oversized the length of the navigation bar to remark the wrong behaviour of the style.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: verdana;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: blue;
  display: space-around;
  z-index: 1;
}
nav a {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 200%;
  text-align: center;
}
nav a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: selectanim 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation: selectanim 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes selectanim {
  from {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  to {
    background-color: purple;
  }
}
@keyframes selectanim {
  from {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  to {
    background-color: purple;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a>1 link</a>
  <a>2 link</a>
  <a>3 link</a>
  <a>4 link</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: I think `display: space-around` should be `justify-content: space-around`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were on the right track. vertical-align:middle is what you need, however it only works if your element is a table cell. so with css you can set the display to "table-cell" and remove "float:left" and set the parent (nav) to behave like a table and it should work:

```
nav {
   display: table
}

nav a {
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y75tbhx5/) for you. Note that i have removed parts of the css to keep answer clean. Hope that helps

Comment: This one doesn't meet OP requirements. If you add hover you see the issue.

Comment: `vertica-align` applies to inline-level and table-cell elements. It also applies to `::first-letter` and `::first-line`.

Comment: Thanks! I think using flex boxes wasn't helping, so displaying the nav content as a table/set of cells made the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a CSS class to your "a" tags in the html like so:

```
<a class="vert" onclick="showArticle('...')">1 link</a>
```

Where the CSS for .vert would be:

```
.vert {
 padding-top: 15%;
}
```

You can play with that padding percentage and adjust it to better fit your site, or make it a fixed value... up to you.

link to [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tzhben/hbp9hfy1/)

Give it a shot. Just gives you a bit more control over the "a" element.

Comment: what if the text inside <a> breaks inside 2 lines then it won't be vertically centered anymore

Comment: you could write media queries and adjust the font size to accommodate for smaller screens? Or, there are CSS rules that you can apply to stop text from breaking into 2 lines... perhaps I'm not understanding the question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, if you reduce the length of the nav bar, you can realize that the links are not properly aligned and overflows in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are already using flexible boxes, you could turn your links to flexible containers.

This way you can use `align-items: center` to center their contents vertically:

```css
nav > a {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center; /* Instead of text-align: center */
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: verdana;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  top: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
nav > a {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 200%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
nav a:hover {
  -webkit-animation: selectanim 0.5s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation: selectanim 0.5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes selectanim {
  from {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  to {
    background-color: purple;
  }
}
@keyframes selectanim {
  from {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  to {
    background-color: purple;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a>1 link</a>
  <a>2 link</a>
  <a>3 link</a>
  <a>4 link</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks! But in my opinion i prefer to display content as a table, since stylesheet is more polished.